# MeteorJS not running external script.js on reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm currently running a compiled scripts.js file that activates a bunch of various UI capabilities (masonry, navbar, etc.) using the onRendered method.

```
Template.mainLayout.onRendered( function() {
    $.getScript('js/scripts.js');
});
```

My issue is, if I navigate to another page like /team, the script doesn't rerun, meaning in other pages, the masonry does not work anymore. Additionally, when I come back to the home page, the script also breaks, making the nav bar broken.

Please let me know if I'm using this function wrong?

Comment: Are you using the `mainLayout` in iron router?

Comment: Nope I am using flow router and blaze layouts. I am now loading the script directly in the scripts.js file with the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re hosting the scripts yourself, put them in your `client/compatibility` folder. Meteor will automatically include them in your app.

If you want to load them from CDN, edit your `client/index.html` folder to add a `script` tag.

Then in your `onRendered` callback, put the code that *initializes* your custom scripts, e.g. `this.$('table').datatable()` or whatever.

Comment: Getting to a closer solutionn now. Loading them via client/compatibility, and I've now scoped in the the code that's not being reloaded. However onRendered only initializes my scripts, how can I reinitialize that script on every reload (to a new route)?

Comment: If `onRendered` isn’t rerunning, it’s because your template isn’t rerendering—even if it disappears and returns (i.e. you change routes and return). To force it to rerender, it needs to contain a variable that changes; for example, a helper that returns `Date.now()` or somesuch. And if that feels hacky, that’s because it is—if _you_ think your template needs to rerender when Meteor thinks it doesn’t need to, something larger is probably wrong. I suggest you post your specific circumstances/code (including jQuery plugins or the like that you may be trying to initialize) in a new question.

Comment: I tried this:
`Template.mainLayout.helpers({
 reactivity: Date.now()
});`

This is just for a learning project, so hacky is good. However, it still doesn't seem to force rerender, even if I set a changing variable.

Answer (score 0):

Eddie, .getscript() is an async function, so you need to specify a calback. I needed to load in meteor an external JS for a leaflet plugin. Using async, defining callback functions did the hack:

```
    $.getScript('js/l.control.geosearch.js', function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        $.getScript('js/l.geosearch.provider.google.js', function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
            new L.Control.GeoSearch({
                provider: new L.GeoSearch.Provider.Google(),
                position: 'topcenter',
                showMarker: false,
                retainZoomLevel: true,
            }).addTo(map);
        })
    })
```